# How to get the numeric value progmatically from the sliderExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**what I tried:**

**MarkUP:**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TextBox2"  Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1"  TargetControlID="TextBox2"  BoundControlID="Label1" Maximum="200" Minimum="100" runat="server">
    </asp:SliderExtender>
```

**Output:**

[image]

now how can I get the value shown "100" progmatically in my C# code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with SliderExtender1.Value

```
var result = SliderExtender1.Value;
```

Comment: Nope. This guy asked this same question 5 min ago, I've flagged the older as duplicate

Comment: how to get the Label1.Text value when the slider changes without clicking any button ?

Comment: @AndreCalil couldn't u answer perfectly without flagging ? if u could do, I wouldn't do it :D

Comment: without posting on server side you can try with javascript

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud Note that this question is much better described than your previous post, that's why it's easy to see what's going on. It's hard to give a clear answer to a unclear question, you know?